# Loops with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was aiming to make this problem shorter with less variables and to only mutate the original array1, but after I noticed that `addedOddNumbers` (value of 9) was not adding to the odd numbers of `array1` while using a for loop I decided to break it down as much as possible.

When I started to break it down as shown below I then tried adding `addedEvenNumbers` to `over10` with the **for loop**. This worked and gave me **23, 21,** but the same if statement above with `addedOddNumbers` to `under10` prints me **2, 4, 9**.

Meanwhile `addedEvenNumbers` prints out **23 and 21** which was what I was looking for originally with the `addedOddNumbers` too. Can someone please explain why that although they are the same exact if statement/expression that one is iterating through and adding while the other is not?

**Note:** I'd like to see this solved as close as possible to to what I have written out. I have seen other solutions, but I can't read the other solutions to be able to answer my own question.

```js
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {
  let addedOddNumbers = 0 // 9 
  let addedEvenNumbers = 0 // 6
  let under10 = [] // 1, 3, 5
  let over10 = [] // 17, 15
  let result = [] // should be 10, 12, 14, 23, 21 --- current result is 2, 4, 9, 23, 21
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] % 2 === 1) {
      addedOddNumbers += array2[i]
    }
    if (array2[i] % 2 === 0) {
      addedEvenNumbers += array2[i]
    }
    if (array1[i] < 10) {
      under10.push(array1[i] + addedOddNumbers)
    }
    if (array1[i] > 10) {
      over10.push(array1[i] + addedEvenNumbers)
    }
  }
  console.log(addedOddNumbers)
  console.log(addedEvenNumbers)
  console.log(under10) // why????
  console.log(over10) // this works fine but why not under10?
  result.push(...under10, ...over10)
  console.log(result)
}

console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
// expected log [10, 12, 14, 23, 21]
```

Comment: You may wish to explore the `else` keyword

Answer (score 0):

It's not the final result of `addedOddNumbers` and `addedEvenNumbers` that is added to the values of `over10` and `under10`, but their current value inside the loop. The `over10` values are correct because they are at the end of the array and by then all the even numbers are already added to `addedEvenNumbers`.

Comment: under10 and over10 are both their own arrays with values though because I created them to be so i don't have to change array1, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "over10 is correct because they are at the end".

Comment: @DeBoer753, I meant that the values, that are greater than 10, are at the end of array1. If they were moved to the beginning of the array, value of over10 would be wrong too.
In such situations it is worth trying the solution with different inputs to see how the algorithm behaves. First start with trivial examples, gradually adding more input and see which step breaks it.
Also a debugger or more verbose logging inside the loop would make the analysis faster.